# Bash cd into subdirectories with increment name

Tags: bash, file, increment, redhat, cd

I have a list of folders in current directory with name "S01.result" up to "S15.result", amongst other stuff.  I'm trying to write a script that cd into each folder with name pattern "sXX.result" and do something within each subdirectory.

This is what I'm trying:

```
ext = ".result"
echo -n "Enter the number of your first subject."
read start
echo -n "Enter the number of your last subject. "
read end

for i in {start..end};
do
  if [[i < 10]]; then
    name = "s0$i&ext"
    echo $name
  else 
    name = "s$i$ext"
    echo $name
  fi

  #src is the path of current directory
  if [ -d "$src/$name" ]; then 
    cd "$src/$name"
    #do some other things here 
  fi
done
```

Am I concatenating the filename correctly and am I finding the subdirectory correctly? Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: You have a number of errors in this script. Run this through http://shellcheck.net to catch many of them. Also some typos.

Answer (score 2):

You said you need to `cd` into each folder that matches the pattern, so we can iterate through all files/folders in current directory for those subdirectories that match the desired pattern.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get current working directory
src=$(pwd)

# Pattern match as you described
regex="^s[0-9]{2}\.result$"

# Everything in current directory
for dir in "$src"/*; do

    # If this is a directory that matches the pattern, cd to it
    # Will early terminate on non-directories
    if test -d $dir && [[ $dir =~ $regex ]]; then
        cd "$dir"
        # Do some other things here 
    fi
done
```